# On Clicking link, Fade down page play video and then go to page

Tags: jquery

Below is the code i'm trying to use, basically i want the user to click a link, in this case to start the 'experience', so i have preventDefault so it doesn't go to straight there. Run the videoStart function, fade out the elements i don't want visible, show the one that i do (which was hidden to start). Then it should play and add an event to load the newpage function (the link that was clicked) when the video ends.

And i can't get it to work, i'm also very new to jQuery and javascript. I have a function that fades the page up and down on when you click the link, i just can't seem to get it to play this video first for this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").show();
    $(".startvideo").hide();
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".startlink").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $("body").videoStart();
    });
    $("body").function videoStart() {
        $(".fader").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".startvideo").show();
        $(".startvideo").play();
        $(".startvideo").addEvent("ended", newpage);
        $("body").function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;}
    }
});
```

Comment: You're writing wrong code like : `$("body").function videoStart() {`

Comment: Please check the Console in the Developer Tools (F12) in the browser and solve syntax errors and runtime errors first.